# Spring boot dependency inject based on country

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to achieve dependency injection based on which country calls my endpoint on runtime so I have the following setup.

```java
public interface Client {
  void call(Data data);
} 

@Profile({"prod"})
public class ClientA implements Client {
  @Override
  public void call(Data data) {
    // implementations goes here
  }
}

@Profile({"dev"})
public class ClientB implements Client {
  @Override
  public void call(Data data) {
    // implementations goes here
  }
}
```

But this setup is now enough since this only depends on which environment the application is running on. I have looked on springs `@Condition` annotation but it does not seem to be enough. What I want to achieve it to be able to define a property in my properties file which defines which countries a given impl should be initilized for on runtime. So something like:

```java
@Profile("${client.a.countries}")
public class ClientA implements Client {
  @Override
  public void call(Data data) {
    // implementations goes here
  }
}
```

and then in my application.propeties files I just define `client.a.countries=DE,GB,ES`. Is there any way of achieving this? So when the frontend calls my endpoint I know which country it is calling from and thereby should know which implementation to use. Am I a pursuing this wrongly should I be looking into doing some kind of Factory pattern implementation to achieve my goal or is it possible with Spring?

Comment: What do you meant by "I also should be able to know which implementation to use." ? how will you know this?

Comment: @pvpkiran I have edited the formulation I  hope it is more understandable now, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your english is gud enuf. I understood what you said. But I am asking how will you select  an Implementation based on country? there needs to be a mapping right? You can initialize which implementation class should be active based on `@Profile` or `@Condition` or something else, But finally u need a map right?

Comment: *"when the frontend calls my endpoint I know which country it is calling from"* Is that because the frontend sends a country code on every request? --- *"I just define `client.a.countries=DE,GB,ES`"* If you have implementations for more countries than that, why not initialize all of them? I mean, if you have an implementation for `FR`, why not initialize French, so a French client can use the endpoint too? Unless the initialization is extreme slow per country, or takes up a huge amount of memory per country, there is no reason to limit the countries on the server/backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this once by creating a ClientRegistry in which all Clients gets registred with the country they are intended for (a Map or so)

```
public class ClientRegistry {
    private Map<String,Client> clients ;

    @Autowired
    public ClientRegistry(List<Client> clients) {

        this.clients = clients.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Client::getCountry, Function.identity() )) ;
    }

    public Client getClient(String country) {
        return clients.get(country);
    }
}
```

In the client Interface you have to add `getCountry`

```
public interface Client
{
    void call(Data data);

    String getCountry();
}
```

Now you have the option to let ClientRegistry implement the Client functions and delegete the calls to the appropriate Client or in the Cotroller you call the Client always like `clientRegistry.getClient(country).call(data)`

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it asap, currently looking into something else, I'll let you know if I made it work!

Comment: Finally found the time to take a look at it and it seems to work I will add an edit to show how I did it but resembles pretty much as you put it, thanks @Turo